# How to read a date in SimpleDateFormat from a JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, date-format, jformattedtextfield

I have the following code for a `JFormattedTextField` which accepts a date entered by the user.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
JFormattedTextField DOB = new JFormattedTextField(df);
```

Now how do I read the date from the `JFormattedTextField` when the user submits the form?

For example if it was a `JTextField` we use `fieldname.getText()`.

Comment: You can use `getValue()` and cast it

Comment: voting to close as too broad (we aren't help desk) without an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, read Oracle tutorials avoud JFormattedTextField and JSpinner (maybe there is better explanation), as aside XxxDateFormat hasn't something with returned value (getValue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `getText`, but that will only return you the value the user entered.

If you call `getValue` it will return a `Date` object (or `null` if the text is invalid).

You can use the `DateFormat` to format the `Date` value, but I'd leave it as `Date` until you need to do something else with it, it's more flexible that way

Comment: So do I just write `DOB.getValue()`?

Comment: That would be my choice

Comment: But that shows an error saying "Objects cannot be converted to string"

Comment: It will be a Date and you will need to cast it

Comment: So I casted it like this `(SimpleDateFormat) DOB.getValue()` and it is giving a new error "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.text.SimpleDateFormat"

Comment: No, the value coming from the `JFormattedTextField` will be a `java.util.Date`, so you need to cast the value to a `Date`